# Telugu language quotation in/with babel

Tags: languages

I need to write Telugu quotation in English (using `babel`) documentation. I want 2 or 3 lines quotation in telugu. I am using :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{babel}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately there is no telugu language support in babel so far.

Comment: You just want 2 or 3 lines? Then full support of [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) is surely not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

For just a couple of lines, here is what you can do currently with `luatex`, which is the recommended engine (besides `xetex`) for the so-called ‘complex scripts’. No Telugu font is included in TeXLive afaik, and Vani is a Windows font.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\babelfont[telugu]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Vani}

\begin{document}

English text. \foreignlanguage{telugu}{భారతదేశంలో అత్యధికంగా మాతృభాషగా
మాట్లాడే భాషలలో తెలుగు నాలుగో స్థానంలో ఉంది.} English text.

\end{document}
```

[image]